# Maven dependencies for writing Spring AOP programs?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-aop

I am trying to learn Spring AOP programming using Spring 5. I am going through online materials.

I discovered that AOP is a concept, similar to OOP; and with AOP, OOPs becomes more powerful.

Now, I am trying to do some hands-on coding for AOP with Spring framework, version 5. I am going to use Maven as the build tool.

I am not clear on what are the various dependencies that we have to use in pom.xml, for example do we need to use: `spring-aop`, `spring-aspects`, `aspectj`etc.

What are the various Maven dependencies that we have to add in pom.xml to be able to write using Maven tool, Spring 5 AOP programs?

Comment: Aspect-J is not required; you can do this with vanilla Spring AOP.  This would be easier if you used Spring Boot 2.0.  It's an opinionated version of Spring that uses Spring version 5.0.

Comment: @duffymo: Thanks for your reply,  don't want to use spring boot, it hides "everything", and as a started want to know some of the concepts. Could you please help with some more details?

Comment: I would recommend that you change your mind.  Spring Boot isn't hiding; it's being opinionated.  You can still do Spring AOP using Spring Boot.  I think this should be sufficient: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.0.0.M5

Answer (score 7):

Its very simple, in order to work spring With AOP, You need aspectjweaver Library existe on the classpath of your application (version 1.6.8 or later).use this dependency to achieve that

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.13</version>
</dependency>
```

As they mention in docs

> To enable @AspectJ support with Java @Configuration add the
>   @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation:

You can find more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-enable-aspectj-java)

The only spring dependency to make something work with AOP is the famous spring-context :

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want a working example check my project in [github](https://github.com/zanguime/yard/tree/SpringAOP) which contains basic Maven AOP example based on spring

Comment: The `spring-aop` dependency is mandatory too

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use CGLIB proxies in Spring without Spring Boot (and any starter dependencies of Spring Boot) then you need **aspectjweaver** besides spring-context, spring-aop dependencies.

Be careful not to add any of the dependencies if they already exist among your Maven dependencies - adding the same dependency with multiple versions may lead to a failing build.