# What jars do I need for Spring AOP for version 5

Tags: spring, jar, spring-aop

As of version 4 of Spring, these are the jars needed to use Spring AOP:

```
aopalliance.jar
aspectjrt.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar
spring-aop-4.0.0.M2.jar
```

But for version 5, what are the jars needed other than

```
spring-aop-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar
```

And where do I find them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467234/maven-dependencies-for-writing-spring-aop-programs/48628216

Comment: I doubt you ever need both _aspectjrt.jar_ and _aspectjweaver.jar_ because the latter is a superset of the former. So the weaver should always be enough, not need to add the runtime too because the weaver contains it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the minimum set of dependencies that I required to run an annotations based Spring applciation

1. spring-context-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar
2. spring-beans-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar
3. spring-expression-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar
4. spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar
5. spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar
6. spring-jcl-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar

and additional dependency for Spring AOP

- aspectjweaver-1.9.5.jar

You may download the entire spring distribution based on the release from [here](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/) or from any maven repository by searching with individual jar name.

Comment: what's the difference between `spring-aop` and `spring-aspects` ? I found the latter included in the latest distribution.

Comment: please go through this documentation section: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj