# Does Spring have a JAR artifact that includes only the base spring annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Going through Spring maven artifact which had only basic annotations like  `@Component`, `@Configuration`, `@Bean`, etc...

Does such artifact exist? Or Do I need to build one like that?

The reason to do this is that I'm refactoring a Java library that was built to run only on CDI environments; now, the library needs to support Spring environments also; so, I need to add to some classes annotations like: `@Component` and `@Bean`, to some of the library classes.

The idea here is to add a compile dependency to a Spring artifact that includes only such annotations; this way, CDI library consumers will not import the Spring Framework, only its basic annotations.

**Note:** I have found that `spring-context` includes some of the required annotations (stereotypes and context package), but I will need to prune the artifact for above mentioned specifications. Ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I upvoted because the question can be informative / helpful when you don't ask for a jar with only the annotations (that not exist) but ask how to solve the problem you have. It's more a design issue in my opinion. Maybe that's not clear in the way how the question is asked right now.

Comment: Not an answer to the question , but I had [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59872374/4214241) an SO question which identified the bare minimum set of jars required for an annotation based spring application . Also I think the spring documentation on [executable jar format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html) would provide pointers for your design. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the annotations are part of other jar files and there is no jar file that only includes the annotations.

What you can do to solve this and is AFAIK also the common way how to do this is to build an extension/additional jar for your library.

So you get something like this:

1. yourlibrary-core -> with all core functionality of the library
2. yourlibrary-ext-spring -> extension of you *yourlibrary* with all the glue code for use it in combination with Spring. In this project you can add the Spring dependencies.

To use your *yourlibrary* in a project in combination with Spring you need both dependencies on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Just building on Jasper's answer, the core library need not have any spring annotations.

The spring extension can have one or many `@Configuration` class with the `@Bean` methods where you are establishing the beans required in the application. So you wouldn't need to even use the @Service, @Component annotations at all.

The core library in most cases would need to use a constructor for the dependencies of a class which would act as a service